# term describing the fact that the predecessors share their experience with successors

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What's the term in English describing the fact that some predecessors share their experience with their successors?

For example:

> The major flaw of this company is that the experienced ones leave too
>   early and don't share the results of their experiments with the new
>   arrivals. A a result, the new ones have to start from scratch and do the
>   same experimentation, and as soon as they come up with some results,
>   they also leave without even having any interaction with the next
>   ones. So that's the whole problem - there is no
>   ________________________ in this company.

1) succession?

2) inheritance?

3) passing-on of knowledge?

4) inheritance of experience?

5) transfer of experience?

6) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is **knowledge transfer**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_transfer):

> Knowledge transfer refers to sharing or disseminating of knowledge and providing inputs to problem solving. In organizational theory, knowledge transfer is the practical problem of transferring knowledge from one part of the organization to another. Like knowledge management, knowledge transfer seeks to organize, create, capture or distribute knowledge and ensure its availability for future users. It is considered to be more than just a communication problem. If it were merely that, then a memorandum, an e-mail or a meeting would accomplish the knowledge transfer.

When an employee has only a few weeks left at a company, management will often ask them to help instruct people who will take over for them—or have the document what they do. This is all a form of transferring their knowledge to somebody else.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think "experience transfer" will also work? Also, in that Wiki article that you have quoted, in "See also" section, there are links to terms "institutional memory" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_memory ) and "transfer of learning" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_of_learning ), what do you think about them?

Comment: @brilliant At least for me, *knowledge transfer* is the most common of the terms. To transfer learning or experiences doesn't sound quite right, although it would be understood. I think I might also prefer *recorded knowledge* to *institutional memory*. It also depends on whether you want to emphasize an action that is taking place or something that already exists.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase I've often heard for this is *"institutional knowledge."*

"Succession" usually refers to how authority is transferred.

"Inheritance" I've never seen applied outside of "gifts from dead people."

The other three aren't idiomatic phrases as far as I know.

Comment: I have also heard, even more frequently, "institutional *memory*".